WCS Commerce unit Testing method in TaskCmd resulting NamingManager.getURLContext cannot find the factory for this scheme: ejblocal
I am trying to write a unit test for a method in a task command with JUNIT using PowerMockito.
In the method to be tested, there is a AccessBean which I am using with findBy methods to get some data. But it's throwing the below error:
NamingManager.getURLContext cannot find the factory for this scheme: ejblocal
Example Testing code:
MyCustomTaskCmdImpl mytask = new MyCustomTaskCmdImpl();
CommandContext context = new CommandContextImpl();
context.setStoreId(storeid);
context.setUserId(userId);
mytask.setCommandContext(context);

TypesProperty responseProperty = Whitebox.invokemethod(mytask , 'methodTobeTested', argument);

Example methodTobeTested:
...
AccessBean ab = new AccessBean();
ab.findById(id);
...

This findby method is throwing error :
javax.naming.ConfigurationException: NamingManager.getURLContext cannot find the factory for this scheme: ejblocal
